# What is the purpose of NLSTERRITORY session variable in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What is the purpose of `NLSTERRITORY` session variable in Oracle? If I change `NLSTERRITORY` point to a different country what does it do? Does it change any date parameter? Because always 10Nov2010 is Wednesday. What difference does it make if I change the territory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quote](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-nls.html):

> Specifying an NLS parameter means that any User Session NLS parameters (or the lack of) will not affect evaluation of [the query/function/stored procedure/etc].

The language and territory components of NLS_LANG set the default values for the other NLS parameters, such as:

- date format
- numeric characters
- collation

Reference:

- [11g NLS_TERRITORY documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_options074.htm)